# D3 barchart not populating.

Tags: javascript, math, random, svg, d3.js

I am trying to create a bar-chart using D3. However, the bar chart is not populating. The following is my code:

```
 var data = [Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random()]

var height = 900 
var width = 600 

var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([0, width])
    .domain([0, d3.max(data)])

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0])
    .domain([0, 500])

var svg = d3.select(".barchart").append('svg')
    .attr("height", height)
    .attr("width", width)    

var rect = svg.selectAll('rects')
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append('rects')
    .attr("height", function(d, i) { return height - y(d) })
    .attr("width", function (d, i) { return x(d) })
    .attr("x", function(d, i) { return x(i) })
    .attr("y", function(d, i) { return y(d) })
    .attr("fill", "blue")
```

Answer (score 0):

There is more than one issue so I'll just list them out.

Changes to your x and y scales. Yours were a bit off.

```
var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([0, width])
    .domain([0, data.length]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([0, height])
    .domain([0, d3.max(data)]);
```

Change 'rects' to 'rect'.

```
var rect = svg.selectAll('rect') // <-- here
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append('rect') // <-- and here
```

Lastly the logic for your x, y, width, and height calculations were off.

```
.attr("height", function(d, i) { return y(d); })
.attr("width", width / data.length - 1)
.attr("x", function(d, i) { return x(i); })
.attr("y", function(d, i) { return height - y(d); })
```

Make sure you are using semicolons.

http://jsfiddle.net/gnouvg6z/

Comment: @ihoworko. Thanks for the help. I look forward to your example ( I am actually going for a vertical bar chart)

Comment: @pandoo Take a look, hopefully that's what you are looking for.

Comment: It is. I have a couple questions. Why does rects need to be rect? Is this a special d3 convention? Also, is the -1 in the width section the barpadding you added?

Comment: 'rects' isn't an svg element, 'rect' is. I suppose you could use 'rects' in the svg.selectAll statement, but you must use 'rect' in the .append statement. The -1 is to just get the 1px spacing between the bars, you can remove that and add a border, or whatever you like.